# Multiple (infinite) inputs from user

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm working on a code that takes in the numbers you want to test and it gives you back all the common multiples of those numbers. But for that I need a command that takes all the numbers the user wants to input and work on them. The user inputs x numbers and the program gives you back all the common multiples of those numbers embedded in x. Any help?

Comment: Your title and question body contradict each other. In the title, you say the user inputs are infinite. But in the body of the question, you say that the user will enter **x** numbers. Which is it?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: I don't want to limit how many numbers the user inputs, I want the input limit to be infinite

Comment: Well the duplicate linked should give you something of what you're looking for.